# Can I get (probably computed) property value without object function calling?

Tags: javascript

I apologize for perhaps trivial question, but I am a little confused now. 
Here is my definition of Rectangle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Fiddling</title>
        <script>
            function Rectangle() {
                this.left = arguments[0];
                this.top = arguments[1];
                this.right = arguments[2];
                this.bottom = arguments[3];
                this.width = function(){
                    return this.right - this.left;  
                }; 
                this.height = function() {
                    return this.bottom - this.top;  
                }
                this.Assign = function (ARectangle) {
                    this.left = ARectangle.left;
                    this.top = ARectangle.top;
                    this.right = ARectangle.right;
                    this.bottom = ARectangle.bottom;
                }   
            }

            var R = new Rectangle(100, 100, 400, 500);
            alert(R.width); //shows function definition
            alert(R.height); //shows function definition
            alert(R.width()); //shows proper value
            alert(R.height()); //shows proper value
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRectReadOnly) is the (seemingly?) similar example, where is some kind of rectangle too  - DOMRectReadOnly, but the properties width and height are obviously not functions. I wonder, how they accomplished introduce read only property (width and height), which are probably difference between borders - and hence functions. I would like to have these nice shaped properties too. ;-)

Thanx for tutoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done through [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'width', {
    get : function(){
        return this.right - this.left;
    }
});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'height', {
    get: function(){
        return this.bottom - this.top;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Object.defineProperties(this, {
    width: {
        get: function(){
            return this.right - this.left;  
        },
    },
});
```